# built-in webcam and microphone not working (12.02 and 14.04)

Tags: webcam, microphone

Today for some reason I've realized that my webcam and microphone are not working any more, I've decided to upgrade to 14.04 (using that as an excuse, and assuming that after it the problem would be gone). Sadly nothing happened.

Strangely enough the laptop seems *not* to recognize neither the webcam nor the microphone, However* the audio output works perfectly fine.

*What can I do?*

**Edit 1:** Output of `hardinfo` input devices:

```
-Input Devices-
 Lid Switch
 Sleep Button
 Power Button
 Power Button
 AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
 Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0
 Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0
 Microsoft Microsoft® 2.4GHz Transceiver v7.0
 SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
 Video Bus
 Video Bus
 HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm      : 7=
 HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm      : 3=
 HDA Intel PCH Headphone
 HDA Intel PCH Line Out
 HDA Intel PCH Line
 HDA Intel PCH Mic
```

**Edit 2:** Output of `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 147e:1002 Upek Biometric Touchchip/Touchstrip Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 8086:0189 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF114M [GeForce GTX 675M] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5289 (rev 01)
03:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0a)
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1030 [Rainbow Peak] (rev 34)
05:00.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): JMicron Technology Corp. IEEE 1394 Host Controller (rev 30)
```

**Edit 3:** In windows the webcam is working perfectly.

Comment: Maybe your hardware died? Does `hardinfo` show it under "Input devices"?

Comment: here is the hardinfo report. I'm not sure if helps =).http://txt.do/6d0c

Comment: Can you output `lspci` and `lsusb` too? (just to be absolutely sure)

Comment: of course =).
http://txt.do/6dov

Comment: I have no more clue!  :-( Deleted my answer and upvoted your question so it'll attract someone better then me!  Good luck! And I would put Edit 3 on the top too!  ;-)

Comment: Something weird happen. I've checked again hardinfo and the webcam is there ¬¬. Should I delete my question?.

Comment: Damn!  Why didn't I think of that before?  I suspect you might have pressed a hardware switch accidentally!  New answer???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following:

- If the camera is **ex**ternal, check the cable and/or port it is plugged in.
- If the camera is **in**ternal, press the hardware switch for the camera <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> (or another function key or sometimes a button on the camera itself or ...)
- On very rare occasions, on a dual boot system, the camera might have been turned off inside Windows and then it needs to be activated there again if the BIOS doesn't allow that.

Comment: Hey Fabby, lucky for me you are wrong. When I went to windows (yes I have dual boot) the cam works perfectly.
So there is something else happening. What can I do?

Comment: you were completely right. Stupid me. It is interesting though that the hardware information dissapears completely with the button huh.